# Magento tiny tweaks for conversion & capture email as first step

Tags: extensions

I was viewing this when I realized the following amongst many other tips.

1. Capture the email address asap
2. Follow up using email

Currently Magento offers a first step where one can continue as guest or login. Previously we had a plugin to skip the first step and this increased conversion. Currently that doesnt work with our template.

I was thinking: with all this knowledge. I have never seen an extension that focuses solely on the in between page (first step) and offers enter your email here field (JS to save) OR social logins.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/webinars/conversion-engineering-tiny-tweaks-huge-reward

**Question:** Does an extension exist that focuses on the in between step and is aimed at capturing the email address asap? (either via input or social login)

UPDATE: http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2848-4-Ways-of-Capturing-More-Email-Addresses-and-Increasing-Conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inchoo offers a [free social login plugin](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/) that you might want to check out.

For capturing the email address as quickly as possible, I haven't found a plugin that offers this in a decent way but you could eliminate the first step all together and by default creating an account for all unregistered users. You can make the 'password' boxes hidden inputs and fill them with a random string in the billing.phtml

But if you find a better solution please share because it sounds interesting.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was aware of that one. Great solution. Still I am looking for the holy grail for conversion ;P

Comment: If it does exist, please let us know!